# Laravel - using username instead id from other table

Tags: sql-server, laravel, datatable

I'm trying to get `nickname` from `user` table to replace `nik` in `media_order` which is usen to shown in my datatable, as for now the `media_order` in my datatable are still showing order that created based on their `nik` like this :

[image]

and here is my `users` table :

[image]

so, as you can see i'm trying to use the `nickname` to shown in my datatable, instead of their `nik`, and here is my `controller.php` :

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if(auth()->user()->is_admin){
                $data = MediaOrder::get();
            }elseif(auth()->user()->group_id){
                $data = MediaOrder::memberOf(auth()->user()->group_id)->get();
            }else{
                $data = MediaOrder::get();
            }
            return DataTables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->addColumn('action',function($row){
                        $btn = '<a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewMediaOrder" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="View" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm button1 viewMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-eye mr-1"></i>View</a>';
                        if($row->isdisabled == 0 && !auth()->user()->is_traffic){
                            $btn = $btn.'<a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" id="editMediaOrder" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm button1 editMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil mr-1"></i>Edit</a>

                            <a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" id="disableMediaOrder"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm button1 disableMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-power-off mr-1"></i>Disable</a>';
    
                        }
                            return $btn;
                    })
                    ->addColumn('created_by', function($row){
                    return $row->userss->nickname;
                    })
                    ->editColumn('is_traffic_viewed', function($row){              
                        if(($row->is_traffic_viewed == 0 && auth()->user()->is_traffic) && $row->isdisabled == 0){
                            $combo = '<input data-id="'.$row->id.'" type="checkbox" class="checkedTraffic">Check</input>';
                            return $combo;
                        }elseif($row->is_traffic_viewed == 0){
                            $row = "Unchecked";
                            return $row;
                        }elseif($row->is_traffic_viewed == 1){
                            $row = "Checked";
                            return $row;
                        }elseif(!auth()->user()->is_traffic){
                            $row = $row->is_traffic_viewed;
                            return $row;
                        }    
                    })
                    ->editColumn('attachment_name',function($row){
                        $data = json_decode($row['attachment_name'], true);
                        $res = ''; $count = count($data);
                        foreach ($data as $value){
                            $res .= $value;
                            if($count > 1){
                                $res .= ', ';
                            }
                            $count--;
                        }
                        return $res;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action','is_traffic_viewed'])
                    ->make(true);
        } else {
            \Meta::set('title', 'Media Order');
            $groups = Group::all();
            $media_order = DB::table('media_order')->get();
            $moo = MediaOrder::get();
            $selected = auth()->user()->group_id;
            $mediaOrder = MediaOrder::all()->first();
            $users = User::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

            return view('media-order.index')->with(compact('users','moo','groups','selected','mediaOrder'));
        }
    }
```

here is my `UserModel` :

```
public function media()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MediaOrder::class);
}
```

here is my `mediaOrder` model :

```
public function userss()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'id')->get();
}
```

so far, i have tried to edit my `function index` like this :

```
$data= MediaOrder::with('userss')->select('media_order.*')->get();
```

and adding the `editColumn` for replace `nik` as `nickname` like this :

```
->addColumn('created_by', function($row){
                    return $row->userss->nickname;
                })
```

but ended up having error an SQL error like this :

> LOG.error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'id'. (SQL: select [users].*, [id].[media_order_id] as [pivot_media_order_id], [id].[user_id] as [pivot_user_id] from [users] inner join [id] on [users].[id] = [id].[user_id]) {"userId":"100","exception":{"errorInfo":["42S02",208,"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'id'."]}

Anyone maybe have an alternative way or maybe solution for this?, any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of a belongsToMany() method is the intermediate table, not the column which provides the function key.

The giveaway is in your error message where it's looking for :

```
[id].[media_order_id]
```

as 'id' is unlikely to be the name of a table. Sure enough, your userss() method defines 'id' in the place where Laravel is expecting to find the name of the table.

```
public function userss() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'id')->get();
}
```